# Where is this value defined - "(action (mut foo) true)"?

Tags: ember.js, ember-cp-validations

On the surface this is a question about ember-cp-validations but really it's about the `action (mut foo)` construct. I have read the [release notes for when that was first introduced](https://blog.emberjs.com/2015/05/10/run-up-to-two-oh.html) but it doesn't address the issue I'm raising here.

In an Ember.js template, when using [ember-cp-validations](https://github.com/offirgolan/ember-cp-validations),  you can execute validations and control the display of the relevant error message like this .

[image]

When `focus-out` fires a property `showFirstNameError` is updated. That property is subsequently used to control the display or otherwise of the error message.

This works perfectly well and is consistent with the [ember-cp-validation demo](https://embermap.com/video/ember-cp-validations).

But where is the property `showFirstNameError` actually defined ? I was expecting it be part of the `validations` property or in some way part of the component, controller or route but I can't find.

Can anyone help me with this please ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't believe it *needs* to be defined anywhere. In this context it can just be `undefined` because its only purpose is to be a flag value so we don't show the error div. When the component is created and rendered that property is `undefined` and it serves its purpose by being a falsy value. When the focus out event fires, it sets that property to `true` like you said and thus the flag has been flipped.

If you're trying to be nice and make things explicit you can set the value to `null` or `undefined` on the component itself so this sort of situation doesn't confuse the next person:

```
import Component from '@ember/component';

export default Component.extend({

  showFirstNameError: undefined,

});
```

Comment: Thank you stevenelberger. Pointing out that I could define properties on the component itself and use those instead of the (kind of) invisible ones was what I needed to know. It's personal preference but I do prefer making it more explicit and that's what I've now done. Thanks again.

Comment: Octane will help with these kind of confusion as variables should be referenced either as `{{this.foo}}` (component), `{{@foo}}` (property passed in on invocation) or `{{foo}}` (local variable, e.g. defined by `{{let}}` helper). Proposed [strict mode for templates](https://github.com/emberjs/rfcs/pull/496) should enforce these conventions.